# findViewById is returning null

Tags: android

I'm having problem using findViewById. It's returning null.
I'm creating a game and I have an activity that is my menu. From there I create and start my SurfaceView.
But I cannot get the reference to FPS TextView using findViewById.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);

        .
        .
        .

    }

    private void prepareButtonListeners() {
        this.mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.road_view_layout);
            }
        });
        .
        .
        .


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <br.com.roadrun.RoadView
        android:id="@+id/road_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fps_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>


public class RoadView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Context mContext = null;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = null;
    private TextView mFPSTextView = null;

    private RoadThread mThread = null;

    public RoadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        // THIS IS WHERE THE FINDVIEWBYID IS RETURNING NULL
        this.mFPSTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fps_text_view);

        setFocusable(true);

        this.mThread = new RoadThread(this);
    }
```

Do you have guys have a light on this? I already tried to call findViewById in another method after the constructor finishes, but with no success.
Thanks,

Comment: `findViewById `in your activity is getting eclipsed by the one in this inner class. It searches from child views and your surfaceview has no child views. Use `SplashScreen.this.findViewById()` to jump up in scope just for this method instead.

Comment: Thanks by your answer Greg. Its not a inner class, but a separated one. As I showed above, it seens to be the same, but its not. I tried what the guys said bellow with:
    mFPSTextView = (TextView) ((SplashScreen) mContext).findViewById(R.id.fps_text_view);
ant it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View's `findViewById` is searching **for a child of a given view** not in an Activity's layout. So you should call Activity's `findViewById`

```
((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.fps_text_view)
```